# Parsing numbers into point objects in Python

Tags: python, parsing, object, methods

I need to get an input line from the user. It must be a series of numbers 
separated by spaces. I need to parse the input into a series of `Point` objects.
The points are like points on a Cartesian plain (x, y). And finally I have 
to print those point out like (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), etc.

If the input is

```
"0 1 2 3 4 5"
```

the output should be

```
(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5)
```

The code have so far looks like

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __str__(self):
        return ('(%f, %f)' % (self.x,self.y))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    points = []
    usrIn = input()
    tokens = usrIn.split(' ')
    for token in tokens:
        #not sure what to do here ****************
    print(points)
```

Does this code look like it's on the right track?

I'm kinda lost on this assignment. Not sure how objects really work yet, any explanation would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Just for clarification, if the input is "0 1 2 3 4 5" the output should be (0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5)

Comment: Yeah, if you can clarify what input you expect that will make explaining the process more useful.

Comment: The input has to be an even number of integers separated by spaces. tokens is a list of those numbers in string form, and I need to somehow create an object for each group of two integers in the list that represent a point (x, y)

Answer (score 2):

You can split the string on spaces and then zip the alternate elements of the split list.

```
s = "0 1 2 3 4 5" 

x = s.split();
print(list(zip(x[::2], x[1::2])))
```

The 3rd parameter to a slice is the stride. So it takes every 2nd element from the list (0, 2, 4, etc) and the second slice is also a slice with stride 2 but starting from index 1 (1,3,5, etc).

The `list` call is only there to force immediate evaluation for the print statement. It's not required if you will later iterate over the return value of `zip`.

The above outputs `tuples`. If you want to turn them into `Point` objects.

```
points = [Point(*map(float,t)) for t in zip(x[::2], x[1::2])]
for p in points:
    print('%s' % p, end='')
print()
```

It looks a bit magical, but essentially its just calling the `Point` constructor in a loop with each pair of values. The `map(float, t)` part converts the two coordinates to float values (I inferred this from your `__str__` method) and the `*` explodes the tuple into the 2 values for the constructor.

The output is

```
(0.000000, 1.000000)(2.000000, 3.000000)(4.000000, 5.000000)
```

You didn't ask for all the trailing 0's but your `__str__` is printing floats, so I left it like that.

Also in your example you try to print the list itself directly using `print(points)`. If you want each list item to custom print itself in this situation, you should define the `__repr__` function.

Answer (score 1):

```
points = [(tokens[i], tokens[i+1]) for i in range (0, len(tokens), 2)]
```

This should return you a list of the tuples you want.  Drop the **for** loop; it's included in this statement (called a "list comprehension").

You might note that the point coordinates are still strings.  You may want to convert the two items in the tuple to **int**.

Comment: That's a smart way of doing it, and doesn't rely on Python 3 zip or Python 2 itertools/izip.

Comment: Thanks.  I try to keep answers at the OP's general tech level.  Too much magic can scare people into not learning a language.